# How do I mount a Windows folder with cifs on Raspbian

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ntfs, cifs

I'd like to access the music library from my desktop with my Raspberry Pi, and I'd like to do this via Samba/cifs.

I did the following:

Set the folder `Q:\musik` as a shared folder on my Windows machine (which has a local IP of `192.168.1.2`), accessible (read, execute and show folder contents) to any user. It appears as `musik` when I look at the network panel and look at the name of the windows machine.

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
mkdir mountmusik
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.2 mountmusik
```

This results in the contents of `musik`being shown in `mountmusik`.

However, there are things which don't work as I'd like to: Plain txt files appear to consist of whitespace, with the exception of theer unreadable characters at the start of the file.

I'm not sure if I omitted vital information when I tried to mount, or if I should have granted a broader access on the windows machine.

**Edit:** It turned out that there were several issues at work. The mp3 files did not play because I was using a non-functional mp3 player program. Now, playing mp3 files works like a charm since I swapped to VLC after installing 
`mpg123`. This was my main issue, but I'm keeping up the question because the txt files are still not able to be read properly and jpg files are not able to be opened.

Comment: when you say local mp3's play fine ... does that mean that if you copied one of the mp3's from the windows share to the pi first it plays OK?

Comment: I was able to play local files (which I originally copied via SCP) using omxplayer. I assumed it would be no issue to use a different player, namely audacious. It turned out: This was the issue. Switching to VLC allowed me to play the files from the mounted drive.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with iocharset. Try to specify iocharset `-o iocharset=utf8,nounix`

```
mount -t cifs //<IP>/path/to/folder /mnt/temp -o iocharset=utf8,username=Guest,passwd="guest",nounix
```

Also there is [AutoFS](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares) utility.